# Как закрыть хэндл чужого процесса?

Tags: c++

Какой функцией я могу закрыть этот хэндл в чужом процессе если мне известен его адрес 0x15c?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if (wcsstr(objectName.Buffer, L"\\Sessions\\1\\BaseNamedObjects\\") > 0)
{
    HANDLE pDeHandle;
    DuplicateHandle(processHandle, (HANDLE)handle.Handle, NULL, &pDeHandle, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE);
    CloseHandle(&pDeHandle);
    system("pause");
}
```

Код убивает мутекс, но нужный результат получается только после закрытия моей программы, как освободить, что добавить чтобы ненужно было закрывать программу.

Comment: @nick_n_a ошибку выдаёт https://imgur.com/duxntA5

Comment: Тут два способа - 1. Инжекция (Подбросить процессу  CloseHandle что б он сам себе закрыл свой хандл) 2. Писать драйвер. Драйвер может получить доступ к хандлам чужого процесса и закрыть его. Более подробно - нету готовых примеров. Как вариант - можно поискать консольные или оконные программы того же sysinternals, и управляя ими закрыть хандл (или с командной строки, или захватом управления).

Comment: @nick_n_a а как тогда закрывает их программа Process Hacker?

Comment: нет, тут эксепшн, это уже ошибка по памяти 100%, в случае если вы не владелец процесса, то функция CloseHandle вернёт 0 и код ошибки в GetLastError() что-то типа "не хватает привилегий". Покажите ваш вывод приложения, а именно строки "std::cout << Handle.handle". Второе, если дело под виндой, то проще послать окну процесса сообщение WM_QUIT, которое процесс обработает и закроется. Третье, убийство процессов работает не так просто, вашему процессу нужны привилегии PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS и PROCESS_TERMINATE, ну и убивать собственно надо ф-цией TerminateProcess

Comment: @goldstar_labs нет, он хочет прибить Mutant который находится в хандлах процесса "Опера". CloseHandle - закрывает хандл текущего процесса, а не Оперы.

Comment: @ goldstar_labs 0x4B4

Comment: @nick_n_a 
DuplicateHandle(processHandle, (HANDLE)handle.Handle, NULL, 0, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE);

Выполнив эту строку кода, мутекс убивается и его больше не видно в Process Hacker'e но чуство что он не убился а продолжает выполнять свою работу.

Comment: Ну это меняет дело. Допишите `CloseHandle( lpTargetHandle )` только обьявите и задайте lpTargetHandle и hTargetProcessHandle (вы её теряете 0 поставив). А то она  теперь "ничейная" Если не понятно - опубликуйте кусок кода в вопрос. (это третий способ)

Comment: @nick_n_a
вот я добавил кусок кода, вроде бы всё работает, но нужный эффект получается когда моя программа зкарывается. Что мне нужно освободить чтобы нужный результат добиться без закрытия моей программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут пара недочетов

```
HANDLE DeHandle; /*1. У вас не ссылка а нормальный таки хандл*/
if (DuplicateHandle(processHandle, (HANDLE)handle.Handle /*0x15c*/,
    GetCurrentProcess() /*2.указать*/
   , &DeHandle, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)) 
CloseHandle(DeHandle); /*3. Тут не надо & ставить, потому что [1]*/
else {  /* ф-ция не сработала обработать ошибки*/};
system("pause");
```

И ссылка на [DuplicateHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: спасибо всё заработало остановился на этом.
DuplicateHandle(processHandle, (HANDLE)handle.Handle, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)

Comment: Т.е. работает таки без CloseHandle? Но лучше сделать. Цитата *If lpTargetHandle is NULL, the function **duplicates** the handle, but **does not return** the duplicate handle value to the caller. This behavior exists only for backward compatibility with previous versions of this function. You should not use this feature, as you will lose system resources until the target process terminates.* это означает что дублированый обьект продолжает жить, пока не закроется программа которая сделала DuplicateHandle.

Comment: да, я не до конца понял, но у меня он закрывается чуть ниже по коду, вобщем всё заработало как надо, результатом доволен, спасибо за помощь. Всё срабатывает когда закрывается вгот этот хэндл https://imgur.com/Bgp4rGh

Comment: Возможно с Mutant так можно делать, а с другими обьектами - может не прокатить. Лучше сделать как указано в ответе.

Comment: исправил спасибо.